# Get errors in table

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm trying to validate some data in power query by doing type conversion and catching the errors that happen.  I want to then append the error messages to the end of the records where the error appears.  The catch here is that I don't know before hand which field/column the error may appear in.  I convert the data type of all columns, and if a field in a record results in error I need to catch it.

Currently i'm trying something like:

```
let
    Source = #"Site Served Import",
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{{"Date", type datetime}, {"Campaign ID", type any}, {"Campaign Name", type text}, {"Site ID ", type any}, {"Site Name", type text}, {"Placement Name", type text}, {"Creative Name", type text}, {"Creative Size/Length", type text}, {"Buy Type", type text}, {"Planned Impressions", Int64.Type}, {"Planned Media Spend", type number}, {"Delivered Spend", type number}, {"Impressions", Int64.Type}, {"Clicks", Int64.Type}, {"Video Starts", Int64.Type}, {"25% Video Completion", Int64.Type}, {"50% Video Completion", Int64.Type}, {"75% Video Completion", Int64.Type}, {"Video Fully Completed", Int64.Type}, {"Engagements", Int64.Type}, {"Actions", Int64.Type}, {"Source", type text}, {"Action Description", type text}}),
    #"Removed Errors" = Table.SelectRowsWithErrors(#"Changed Type")
```

This bit gives me only the records with errors in them. Then i'm trying to write a function to append those errors to the end of the records.  So far my attack has been to add a custom column for each column with the formula:

```
try [column]
```

Honestly i'm having trouble even trying to add columns in a loop.  I don't think i'm thinking right about m yet.  I'm more of a C type of guy, so this m stuff is strangely counter intuitive.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  The basic approach is to add a Calculated Column using `try [column]`. That will return a nested Record-type column that you can expand a couple of times to get to column.Error.Message.

The easiest way is to get started is to generate an example using the UI, then look at the script it produces.

Here's a good blog on the subject:

https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2013/12/error-handling-in-power-query/

Comment: I don't think this works as it requires you to know the name of your column before using try.  In my scenario the name and number of columns is unknown.

Comment: Well your script already has a specific list of columns in the Changed Type step, where you set the datatypes. If what you say is true, you may have chosen the wrong tool for this job.